# Mocking google with omniauth in rails integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, omniauth

I have a sample project, where user can **login with their google account**, Now i want to **write a test** to verify that user has successfully logged in with his google account. But i don't know how to verify this thing in my test file ?
This is what i have tried now but its not working

```
  OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({
                                                                  :provider => 'google',
 :uid => '1337',
 :info => {
 'name' => 'JonnieHallman',
 'email' => 'jon@test.com'
 }
 request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
 request.env["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google]
```

I am supposing that after this my page content would change but they are same as before

Comment: Unclear question. Please provide some code samples and/or more info.

Comment: Hope its more clear now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the guide on how to do integration tests with Omniauth https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing

basically you'll have something like this in your `spec/rails_helper.rb`

```
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:xing] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({
  :provider => 'google',
  :uid => '123545',
  :info => {
    :name => "Test",
    :email => "test@test.com"
  },
  :credentials => {
    :token => "token",
    :secret => "secret"
  }
  # etc.
})
```

And then have a `login_helper` that does something like

```
def login
  Rails.application.env_config["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google]
  visit root_path
  click_link 'loginBtn'
end
```